# How can I convert my French driving license to a Massachusetts driving license?

Tags: driving, driving-licenses, massachusetts

I live in Boston, I plan to stay there for around 5 months and I have a French international B driving license.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47393/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-how-can-i-convert-my-french-driving).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the local RMV ([MassDOT RMV](http://www.massrmv.com/BranchMap.aspx;); 630 Washington Street, Boston, MA is the most easily accessible in Boston using public transportation) with:

- Passport (+ I-20 if you are on F-1 visa)
- French driving license + translation by the French Consulate (20 USD)
- French "releve restreint" (called "driving record" in the US), which is given by the Prefecture in which the driving license was delivered. It can be sent by mail [1](http://www.massrmv.com/BranchMap.aspx;). We have translate this document ourselves using the template provided on http://www.consulfrance-boston.org/spip.php?article3022, then the French Consulate certifies the translation. (15 USD). To get discounted price for translation, [register](http://www.consulfrance-boston.org/spip.php?article2120) at Consulat Général de France à Boston: (by mail or face to face)
- Social security card. See note 3.
- Fill http://www.massrmv.com/rmv/forms/21042.pdf (can be done at the RMV, they have copies of the form there)

**Note 1**: The "international" driving license that is delivered in France is useless to get a US driving license. You need to have the French driving license.

**Note 2**: To get the French "relevé restreint" by mail: see [Connaître le nombre de points restant sur son permis](http://www.interieur.gouv.fr/A-votre-service/Mes-demarches/Transports/Infractions-aux-regles-de-securite-routiere/Permis-a-points/Connaitre-le-nombre-de-points-restant-sur-son-permis)

http://www.torontois.com/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=1586&start=45:

> Faites un courrier expliquant votre cas avec photocopie du permis et
>   de la carte d'identité à (pas eu besoin d'envoyer de lettre reponse ni
>   de recommandé etc ... cool)
>
> Ministère de l'intérieur, de l'Outre-Mer et des Collectivités
>   territoriales 
>   Fichier national des permis de conduire 
>  
>   Place Beauvau 
>   75008 Paris Cedex 08

The letter I wrote (didn't give much thought about it):

> Franck Dernoncourt  
>  Phone: +33 601 187 123  
>   Address: XXXX, 75013 Paris, France 
>    
>   Email: franck.dernoncoucgcbrt@gmail.com
>
> Bonjour,
>
> Actuellement aux États-Unis pour un PhD de 5 ans, j’aimerais convertir
>   mon permis de conduire français en un permis de conduire américain.
>   Pour cela, j’ai besoin du relevé restreint. Pourriez-vous s’il vous
>   plaît me l’envoyer à l’adresse suivante: XXXX, 75013 Paris, France
>
> Une photocopie du permis et de ma carte d'identité accompagnent cette
>   lettre.
>
> Merci d’avance pour votre aide,
>
> Franck

**Note 3**: Regarding the social security card, http://www.massrmv.com/rmv/forms/21042.pdf says:

> You must also produce your social security number (SSN) that the RMV
>   can verify with the U.S. Social Security Administration (SSA) as
>   having been issued to you.
>
> If you do not have an SSN, an acceptable written denial notice not
>   more than 60 days old, from the Social Security Administration (SSA)
>   is required. You must also provide proof of an acceptable visa status,
>   an I-94, and a current non-U.S. Passport.

**Note 4**: A *relevé d'information intégral de permis de conduire* looks like this:

[image]

Comment: You will also likely need a copy of your I94, which can be obtained from http://www.cbp.gov/i94

Comment: In fact, international driving permit are useless for any purpose without the original driver's license (where and when they are required, you need to have both together).

Comment: Also, if your driving license is in English, and is machine readable, you don't need the international driver's license in most countries.