# How can I get a 1968 international driving permit (French citizen, US permanent resident, with a US driving license converted from a French license)?

Tags: international-travel, driving-licenses, french-citizens, us-permanent-residents

How can I get a 1968 international driving permit?

---

My situation:

- I am French citizen, US permanent resident, and holding a US driving license (converted from a French license),
- My French driving license is being kept in the French Consulate at Boston, Massachusetts, as I [converted my French driving license to a US driving license](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/22413/1810).

I believe that the American Automobile Association (AAA) in the United States  only distributes 1949 international driving licenses.

If this is an option, I would prefer to get a 1968 international driving permit in the US, ideally not too far from San Francisco.

Answer (score 5):

Because the US has not signed the 1968 convention, much less ratified it, you cannot get a 1968 permit on the  basis of a US license.  That your license was obtained in exchange for a French license does not change this.

Therefore, you can only get a 1968 permit on the basis of your French license.  In addition, such a permit is not valid unless accompanied by your French license.  So as long as your French license is impounded in the French consulate, you will be unable to get a 1968 permit.

Whether and how the French authorities would be willing to issue a permit to you [depends on some other circumstances](https://www.service-public.fr/particuliers/vosdroits/F11534), first if all whether you maintain *"résidence normale"* in France.

Comment: @David thanks for pointing that out.  I've edited a bit.  I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: You're welcome, it is clearer. Interestingly, the page you link to says an application may be made by postal mail with a color copy of the front and back of the French license. But as you point out, even if the OP had such copies (and otherwise qualified), until he has his original French license in his possession a French-issued IDP would be ineffective.